# Using Java string method to replace chars inside a string

Tags: java

How to replace characters with another character inside a string.
Can not use arrays, builder, or replace().

Comment: given those weird requirements, I'd try substringA + replacement + substringB

Comment: You cannot replace characters within a string because String in Java is immutable as far as i know. However, you can copy contents of a string one character at a time and replace the character that you want to replace. Place them inside a character array. Then, you can use that character array to construct another string. May not be the best solution but it'll do :D

Comment: can't use arrays =(

Comment: That's just kind of dumb then.  Arrays are fundamental.  I guess you could get cheeky and use a linked list.

Comment: @Squanto oh sorry about that :(

Comment: You could replace arrays with a list then. It's quite easy to use as well :D

Comment: hmm haven't learned list, i guess ill do some research

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment. I suggest you start by turning off your computer and get a piece of paper and a pencil. Try to describe the steps you need to take to solve the problem. If you don't even know how to start this, you should ask your classmates and instructor for help.

Comment: Another suggestion.  Turn the computer back on, Google for "javadoc String" and read the javadocs for the `java.lang.String` method.

Answer (score 3):

you can iterate string char by char and connect each character in a new string and ignore from the character you want to replace

Answer (score 0):

Store the input in a character array. Iterate over the array and check for that character you want to replace and if it is present place the required character in that index.

Comment: can't use arrays =(

Comment: Ok then you can use for loop to iterate over input string ( with maximum of s.length() ). You must have empty string for output. In that for loop you can get each input character by s.charAt(i) and then compare with required character and append to the output string accordingly.